# How to pass a dynamic DataModel to an Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I dynamically build a ASP.NET MVC3 View with some inputfields, but cause of the dynamic creation of the UI, I do not know which inputfields will be available. 
After clicking on a button (search) I want to pass the actual inputdata as an Model(ViewModel) to an Action. Here`s the Problem, I dont know which properties does the Model have and how to pass this dynamic Model/Object to the Action.

I tried to simply do it like so:

```
public ActionResult StartQuery(dynamic request)
{
    var test = request;
    //...
}
```

but don`t know how to handle this dynamic object. If this is the correct way, do I have to use reflection for this or does anybody can give me a tip how to correctly push dynamic data to an Action?

Thanks in advance,
Cordell

-EDIT

Even if I know the input IDs it doesn`t worked out. Keep getting DynamicBinderExceptions.

```
public ActionResult StartQuery(dynamic request)
    {
        string test = request.ArticleNo;
        string test2 = request.ArtNoOfSuppl;
        string test3 = request.ArticleGrp;
       //...
```

These are the exact IDs for the test, I cannot build on the names, the could change.

Comment: do you know the properties you populated to the dynamic view? i mean the ids of the input feilds..

Comment: Are you trying ot build a generic search action

Comment: Hi, the IDs of the inputfield are generated too, depending on the data of the web.config. There is a custom section with settings from which the ui will be build. For example. If the user only adds detailed settings for 3 special input fields, this fields will be build on the ui.

Comment: "`dynamic`" really is only useful if you *KNOW* the fields that will be available at runtime, just not at compile time.  Essentially what you're telling the compiler with `dynamic` is "Don't bother trying to figure this out - I know what I'm doing.  It'll work at runtime, trust me."  If you can't make that promise, then you can't use `dynamic`.

Comment: ok I understand, but do you have an idea how to solve my problem? Even if I know the IDs im getting DynamicBinderExceptions, that the object has no definition for "ArticleNo". Just tested it.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy not entirely true since with the NuGet package Clay you can access properties through indexers E.g. Foo["Bar"] is equavalent to Foo.Bar

Comment: @Rune FS - so what would be the purpose of "dynamic" in that scenario?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy to make it work :) if the object passed in doesn't have an indexer that matches properties added dynamically how would you call either the indexer (if the indexer only exist when bound dynamically) or the properties and what type would you use if not dynamic? Could it be done in another way sure IDictionary<string,object> for one

Comment: I still don't see how it would (*could*) work with dynamic, though - the binder still needs to know an exact type in order to bind correctly.  dynamic doesn't replace strong typing, it just defers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `dynamic`, if you know the names you can fetch them directly from the request:

```
public ActionResult StartQuery()
{
    string test = Request["ArticleNo"];
    string test2 = Request["ArtNoOfSuppl"];
    string test3 = Request["ArticleGrp"];
    ...
}
```

If you don't know them you could still loop through `Request.Params` collection and based on your rules find the parameters you need.